# Syncing NTFS permissions with SMB share permissions

Tags: file-system, windows, powershell

I recently wrote scripts to automate the setup of shares on a server using the `New-SmbShare` cmdlet.  I hadn't realised that this cmdlet doesn't automatically amend the underlying NTFS permissions to honour the SMB permissions.  This script is a generic one which can be run after the SMB permissions are defined to ensure the NTFS rights support the SMB ones.

NB: Since NTFS rights may need to be more permissive than SMB ones, this operation is solely additive; i.e. there is no logic to remove existing rights or to set access to `deny`.

```
function Grant-NtfsSmbSharePermissions {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [string]$ShareName 
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]$inheritanceFlags = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::ContainerInherit -bor [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::ObjectInherit
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]$propagationFlags = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None #all child folders should already know to inherit / if any have custom permissions we don't want to impact them
    )
    process {
        $Path = (Get-SmbShare -Name $ShareName -ErrorAction Stop).Path 
        $NtfsAcl = Get-Acl $Path -ErrorAction Stop

        $type = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow #we filter for allowed access since don't necessarily want deny on an smb to cause deny on ntfs / this is safest

        #provide a simple mapping from the SMB permissions to the related NTFS ones
        #https://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/871338/FileSystemRights_Table2.png
        $fsr = (New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
            Full = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::FullControl
            Change = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::Modify
            Modify = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::Modify #in some documentation the AccessRight is listed as Modify rather than Change; testing suggests that's a typo, but this caters for that scenario just in case
            Read = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::Read
        })

        Get-SmbShareAccess -Name $ShareName -ErrorAction Stop | Where-Object {$_.AccessControlType -eq $type} | ForEach-Object {
            #https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfe70whw(v=vs.110).aspx
            $current = $_
            $fileSystemRights = $fsr."$($current.AccessRight)"
            Write-Verbose "Assiging $($fileSystemRights.ToString()) to $($current.AccountName)"
            $fsar = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule' -ArgumentList @(
                $current.AccountName
                ,$fileSystemRights
                ,$inheritanceFlags
                ,$propagationFlags
                ,$_.AccessControlType
            )
            $NtfsAcl.SetAccessRule($fsar) #NB: this process is additive; i.e. we don't remove any existing permissions which may have been set
        }
        Set-Acl -Path $Path -AclObject $NtfsAcl -ErrorAction Stop
    }
}
```

I'm not that knowledgable about ACL / permissions, so thought it best to share in case I've left any potholes unfilled.

Comment: NB: Just realised that `$type` and `$fsr` definitions should be moved to the `begin` block for improved performance.  I've not amended the above code to reflect to avoid changes from impacting any reviews-in-progress.